Ubuntu Laptop is connected as Audio Device in Android TV
I have paired my Dell laptop which has Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS installed in it. I am trying to send files from the PC to Android TV via bluetooth. However the Ubuntu device is being discoverd as Audio device after connected with bluetooth to Android TV.
How to change this to have files transferred to the TV over bluetooth?

Try with Ubuntu 24.04 live session

I shall try, but any speculation why with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS , it appears as Audio device? Also you suggesting live session as some people cant upgrade right?

why not 20.04? Because newer versions of Ubuntu have better support for better hardware. Why live session? So that you can try Ubuntu without installing, so that before you install, you would already know whether the bluetooth will work properly or not

@ArchismanPanigrahi ok it makes sense. Thanks

Please provide additional information.  Why are you not using a newer version of Ubuntu? (Newer versions have have newer kernels. Which laptop are using?  Provide full model number and part number if possible.  What Bluetooth chipset? What kernel version are you on?   And provide full details on you Android TV with manufacture, model, and part numbers.
